# Plugin error: Plugin 'JSON Model Generator' is compatible with IntelliJ IDEA only because it doesn't define any explicit module dependencies

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, plugins, intellij-plugin, android-json

Why am I getting this error every time I start my IDE? I have not installed any such plugin.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This plug-in is incompatible with Android Studio. You may want to contact the plug-in vendor for help.

Comment: This "Kotlin to JSON" plugin is not giving the error.  The error is talking about "JSON Model Generator".

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a different plugin. In my case (Kubuntu, Android Studio 2020.3) the hack was delete the plugin file from

~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio2020.3/ZOMBI_PLUGIN_NAME.jar

Comment: In MacOS the incompatible plugin was in "~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2020.3/plugins" directory if anyone faces the same issue.